# Several non primary key column in Cassandra, , and use Pycassa

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

My requirement is to have a column family like the following:

```
    mac_ap text,
    proto int,
    stime int,
    total_data int,
    total_assoc int,
    location_id int,
    location_name text
    PRIMARY KEY(mac_ap, proto, stime)
```

I don't think `COMPACT STORAGE` allows this. Also, I want to use pycassa. Is there any way with which I can achieve the above using `Cassandra 1.2` and `Pycassa?`